# Actions-on-google library List and Carousel not working

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

````
    ```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Button, dialogflow, BrowseCarouselItem, BrowseCarousel, Suggestions, List } = require('actions-on-google');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });

app.intent('Welcome', (conv) => {
    conv.ask(new BrowseCarousel({
        items: [
            new BrowseCarouselItem({
                title: 'Title of item 1',
                url: 'https://example.com',
                description: 'Description of item 1',
                image: new Image({
                    url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
                    alt: 'Image alternate text',
                }),
            }),
            new BrowseCarouselItem({
                title: 'Title of item 2',
                url: 'https://example.com',
                description: 'Description of item 2',
                image: new Image({
                    url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/actionsresources/logo_assistant_2x_64dp.png',
                    alt: 'Image alternate text',
                }),
            }),
        ],
    }));
});

// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
````

I'm using the Dialogflow with actions-on-google and I'm facing the issue with it. On creating any rich message response, the bot just crashes without any error. I've also upgraded and downgraded the versions of the actions-on-google library but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you try adding another conv.ask() with an introduction text? Most visual elements require you to atleast send 1 message along with your element.

Comment: If it's crashing, you should check the server logs to see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lists and Carousel with DialogFlow needs an extra simple response like conv.ask("this is a list") before the rich response. As it's written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/selection-responses#carousel)